# "int() argument must be a string" processing output of date.split(':')

Tags: python

I have a function that gets the day from a string structured as DD:MM:YY.

```
def get_day(date):
    day=int(date.split(':'))
    return day
```

I expect the function to return an integer with the number of the day, but instead I get this error

`TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'list'`

Comment: You did a really great job writing your question!

Comment: `split` returns a list of strings.  To select the first of those strings, you can do `int(date.split(':')[0])`

Comment: @rlb.usa, I wouldn't praise a question without a title that actually describes the specific problem. The original title of *"Don't know what it's wrong with the code"* could be applied to 99% of all questions here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
date.split(':')
```

returns a list of strings, 
try

```
date.split(':')[0]
```

to get the first item of that list